# Debian opus troubles

Tags: audio, debian, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

I'm trying to play webm(or mkv) files with vlc. Here's ffmpeg file.webm output

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'webpunk.webm':
  Metadata:
    title           : title
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:03:20.15, start: 0.007000, bitrate: 419 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv), 960x540, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
```

FFplay plays this without problems but vlc says it couldn't decode Opus Audio. I've already installed libopus0, libopus-dev, libopus0:i386, opus-tools, libopusfile0 but nothing helps. What should I do to make vlc play files with opus?

Comment: Support for OPUS was added in VLC 2.0.4, check your software version.

Comment: @Ely it's it's 2.2.1